# Is it possible to treat starting values as variables?

Tags: programming

I have a problem where I am using FindRoot a gazillion times over a grid of parameters.  I need to allow the starting values to vary a bit with the parameters to get it to converge.  Here is a simple example in the spirit of my much bigger problem:

```
f[a_] := x /. FindRoot[x^2 - 1 == a, {x, a - 1, a + 1}]
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, 5}]
```

NIntegrate actually gives an answer (I think it's even right), but it also gives the following errors:

> FindRoot::srect: Value -1.+z in search specification {x,z-1,z+1} is not a number or array of numbers. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[x^2-1==z,{x,z-1,z+1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

It looks like it doesn't like treating the starting values for x as variables.  For some reason, the actual numbers between 0 and 5 in the integral are not being passed to the starting values in FindRoot.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about what you're trying to do, but this doesn't bring up errors:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[x^2 - 1 == a, {x, a - 1, a + 1}]
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, 5}]

(*
-> 9.13129
*)
```

**Edit**

The result is (of course) equivalent to

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + z], {z, 0, 5}]

(*
-> -(2/3) + 4 Sqrt[6]
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't know the syntax a_?NumericQ, so I'm showing my limited knowledge of the program, but I'll look it up and give it a try.  My problem involves integrating over functions of the normal PDF, which has no closed form, so I definitely need the numerical routine.

Comment: belisarius, This worked.  I've got a few hundred thousand solutions to FindRoot with starting values that a funciton of a subset of the parameters.  This ensures that they are in regions that generate solutions.  Then I've got a few hundred thousand numerical integrals of functions with the FindRoot solutions embeded, all solving nicely.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dan Glad to hear that