# How to use NIntegrate in a purely numerical mode?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function that is defined as the smallest root of a given polynomial. Something like this:

```
f[param1_,param2_,param3]:= Module[{roots},
  roots = getRoots[param1,param2,param3];
  Return[Min[roots]];
]
```

The function `getRoots`would build a polynomial and use `Solve[]` to solve it.

I need to integrate `f`numerically, but I keep getting errors:

```
 NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand Min[<<1>>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,300000}}"
```

Using `Manipulate`, I can calculate values along the integration range, that is, the function indeed has numerical values.

I suspect that the symbolic preprocessor tries to analyze the argument of `Min[]`, but it get stuck because the argument is a list of roots of a polynomial.

Since the function `f[]`can be evaluated numerically, it should be possible to integrate it in a purely numerical way, without the symbolic analysis. Is there any way, any choice of integration method to do that?

Comment: Try `NIntegrate[.., Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]` and define the function using `f[param1_?NumericQ,param2_?NumericQ,param3_?NumericQ]:=...`!

Comment: See also [this pitfalls answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037), and these q&a linked there: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/plot-holdall-and-the-color-problem/15876#15876), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17993/using-a-compiled-function-inside-nintegrate-gives-compiledfunctioncfsa-messa/17994#17994), and less closely related [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/is-it-possible-to-treat-starting-values-as-variables/24705#24705).

Comment: Did you put a `_` after `param3` in your real code? As posted here, it seems it shouldn't work. Also, have you checked that e.g. `f[1.,2.,3.]` returns a number not some more complex expression?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: let us take one equation, simple enough for a trial. Let it be

```
 Clear[x, y];
eq = y^5 - y^3 + x == 0;
sl = Solve[eq, y]
```

The result is:

```
(*  {{y -> Root[x - #1^3 + #1^5 &, 1]}, {y -> 
   Root[x - #1^3 + #1^5 &, 2]}, {y -> 
   Root[x - #1^3 + #1^5 &, 3]}, {y -> 
   Root[x - #1^3 + #1^5 &, 4]}, {y -> Root[x - #1^3 + #1^5 &, 5]}}  *)
```

The first of them, for example, is real at 0<=x<=1. Let us check it:

```
Plot[sl[[1, 1, 2]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Here it is shown:[image]

Now let us integrate:

```
NIntegrate[sl[[1, 1, 2]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The answer is:

(*  -1.14189  *)